# Spotipy - Validating successful authentication

Tags: python, spotipy

I was wondering how to validate that a user has correctly entered their spotify developer profile information correctly. I have a file, credentials.py, with 3 constants needed to get a spotify API token. In main.py, I use these constants like so.

```py
def authenticate_user():
    if not credentials.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET or not credentials.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID:
        raise RuntimeError("Spotify credentials have not been set! Check credentials.py")

    os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID"] = credentials.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID
    os.environ["SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET"] = credentials.SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET
    os.environ["SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI"] = credentials.SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI

    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=spotipy.SpotifyOAuth())
    return sp
```

The resulting variable, sp, does not seem to have any methods to verify that it has successfully been validated. On attempting to use any methods, you are sent to a webpage with the corresponding spotify endpoint, showing that the request failed. When exiting the page, no error is thrown and the program hangs. How do I throw an error on invalid information being used to authenticate with the spotify servers?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the spotipy api returns a boolean upon verification, just make an if statement that looks like this:

```
If (sp == True):
  Print('credentials valid')
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this didn't work or wasn't reproducible in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Base on Spotify docs [here](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/en/2.19.0/)

you should get a Spotify.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError
then you can surround the code with a try and except.

you can do it like this:

```
try:
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=spotipy.SpotifyOAuth())
    return sp
except SpotifyOauthError as e:
    raise RuntimeError(f"Spotify credentials didn't work, error={e}")
```

just don't forget to import the exception from Spotify.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError

Comment: The problem is that rather than an error being caught, the program hangs!

Comment: You can use raise an error in the except like you raise when the credentials didn't set.